# Kubernetes: curl works on physical node but NOT in pod

Tags: kubernetes, curl, calico, ssl-handshake

I installed kubernetes (1 controller node and 4 worker nodes).

O.S. Ubuntu 22.04.1
kubernetes v1.26.1
Calico v3.25.0

From a POD I need to get authenticate to an external server.

The request works perfectly when running on the node itself (NOT inside POD), but it doesn't inside a kubernetes POD.

I installed network-tools, this is the yaml file

`apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: network-tools
namespace: tools
labels:
app: network-tools
spec:
replicas: 1
selector:
matchLabels:
app: network-tools
template:
metadata:
labels:
app: network-tools
spec:
containers:
- name: network-tools
image: praqma/network-multitool

I tried this command:
`curl -k  'https://xxxxxxxxxxx/RequestSessionToken' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"Username": "username", "Password": "password", "TokenLifetime": 3600}'`

Response inside NODE (GOOD!):
`{"Token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","UserStatusCode":0}`

Response inside POD network-tools (BAD!):
`curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`

Adding -vvv at the end (inside POD):
`*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx:443...

- Connected to domainname (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#0)
- ALPN, offering h2
- ALPN, offering http/1.1
- successfully set certificate verify locations:
- CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
- CApath: none
- TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
- error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
- Closing connection 0
  curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`

I tried adding several flags like `tls-max tls-version insecure` etc etc without success.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: There are multiple reasons for this issue `error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number` since you are saying that you are using calico. I found that this document might be relevant. Can you confirm whether you are using calico-typha in your configuration, you can find this by using following command `kubectl get services` if there is a service named calico-typho follow this [document](https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/getting-started/kubernetes/hardway/install-node) for installing calico/node with a certificate this will resolve the issue.

Comment: If this didn’t worked we can check and troubleshoot kube-proxy configs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using calico-typa. I found the reason why it happens.
The DNS resolves different IP address when inside the POD.
If I try curl with the IP address resolved in the POD also the NODE returns the same error.